# Why use Polymorphism if sub-classes members are inaccessible

Tags: vb.net

This is my sandpit:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim myCar As Car
    myCar = New sportsCar 

    myCar.numDoors = 4
    myCar.weight = 100  '<<errors here

End Sub

Class Car

    Public numDoors As Integer

End Class
Class sportsCar
    Inherits Car

    Public weight As Integer

End Class
```

Initially I point myCar at the super-class `Car` and then I use polymorphism to instantiate it to the sub-class `sportsCar`.

Why can't I access the subclass's field `weight`? Is there a technique I need to use to access this field or am I just missing the point?

---

**EDIT**
I realize that the following will compile. but the point of the exercise is that I'm trying to understand the idea of *polymorphism*

```
Sub Main()

    Dim myCar As sportsCar
    myCar = New sportsCar() 

    myCar.numDoors = 4
    myCar.weight = 100

End Sub
```

If the sub-class's members are *not* accessible then what is the point of polymorphism?

```
    Dim myCar As Car
    myCar = New sportsCar
```

Comment: If you want to use properties from your child class you should declare it as child class in the first place.

Comment: The short answer to the headline question is, because the super class properties are accesible.

Comment: @Jodrell ..ok but why not just declare & instantiate it as the super class if the child classes members are not accessible? ....just seen your answer now; I'd better read the first!

Comment: I hope my answer explains what polymorphism is and why it is good. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15759433/659190

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual question seems to be,

> "What is the point of polymorphism?"

To Answer,

It allows us to work on all subclasses of a class of types. To illustrate, imagine I have two contrived functions.

```
Sub SetDoors (ByVal car As SportsCar,  ByVal doors As Integer)
    car.NumDoors = doors
End Sub

Sub SetDoors (ByVal otherCar As Car,  ByVal doors As Integer)
    car.NumDoors = doors
End Sub
```

Because Polymorphism is part of the CTS and allowed in VB.Net I don't need to duplicate common functionality for every possible type.

I can omit the specialized `SportsCar` version of the function because `SportsCar` is a polymorph of `Car`. The `Car` version of the function will work for all inheritors of `Car` including `SportsCar`. Without polymorphism this would not be allowed.

---

If you want an abstract member to be implemented on all sub classes, then you mark the class as `MustInherit` and use the [`MustOverride`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hyb29zk8.aspx) keyword.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access `weight` property because `Car` class does not have one. You have to cast your object to `sportsCar` first:

```
CType(myCar.weight, GetType(sportsCar)) = 100
```

Comment: +1 for showing how to cast to the subclass. Although in this instance `DirectCast` is probably more appropriate, since we know `SportsCar` directly inherits `Car`. Also, I'm not sure this answers the actual question. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k6y2h6x(v=vs.110).aspx